# Python request returning 502 gateway error

Tags: python, http-error

I'm working on a python app which sends an encrypted data packet to a remote python server. All code works on my local dev machine but on the production server the request is returning a bad gateway error (502). The remote server is using python 2.7 with nginx. the source server uses Python 3 and Apache. If i point my dev version to the same remote source I also get a 502 error so it seems to be an issue on the remote box (as my local remote is working as expected)

Here's a sample of the relevant portion of my code from the local side.

```
# Encrypt the data and send it
enc = Fernet(config["Encryption"]["key"].encode('utf-8'))
members = json.dumps(members, indent=2).encode()
members = enc.encrypt(members)

data = {"data": members}

response = requests.post("https://sites.url/update/", data=data, verify=True)
response.raise_for_status()
print(response.status_code)
```

At this point the payload (which is just id's and personnel data) is encrypted and sent to the remote sever.

The relevant code from the remote server is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import configparser
import time
import math

from flask import Flask, request, abort, render_template
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

from MySQLdb.cursors import DictCursor
import mysql.connector

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from flask import jsonify

... Other routes etc ...

@app.route("/update/", methods=["POST"])
def update():
        enc = Fernet(app.config["ENC_KEY"])
        data = enc.decrypt(request.form["data"].encode("UTF-8"))
        with open("opt/path/members.json", "w") as fp:
                fp.write(data.decode("UTF-8"))
        return ("OK")
```

As I said this is working locally but the remote call is failing no matter if i call from my dev local source or using the production source.

Nothing is reported to either the apache or nginx logs. I do however get the following when i manually run the python3 main.py command on either source:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/path/member-export/main.py", line 121, in <module>
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 502 Server Error: Bad Gateway for url: https://site.url/update/
```

The other routes on this server can be reached with a browser so the server is there. all encryption keys are the same.

Any ideas?

thanks

*** EDIT ***
I ended up abandoning this method and instead I use ssh/sftp to send a dumped file of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned the entire encryption idea and used paramiko to transfer the data as a file by sftp.